# Using angular 2 - 5 components separately

Tags: angular, angular5

I am working on project which has a complicated shopping cart form. I first did it with jQuery but as Project evolved shopping cart became more complicated. Now I want to rewrite all shopping cart operations in Angular 5.

As I sad I want to some parts of page to be handled by angular not whole page.
My scenario is as follows:

1. In items or item page Angular handles adding to cart operation when user clicks add to cart.
2. There is a minicart dropdown in header, so any changes in shopping cart will update that minicart dropdown.
3. In shopping cart page all operations are handled by angular.

So my problem is:
How can I render only specific components on specific pages?

Comment: Angular is not really built for that use case. You should look into other more suitable options.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I realized it too late I think :), I already spen 4 days trying to implement it

Comment: Angular is a framework, you're supposed to use it entirely. Your goal isn't compatible with the intended use of Angular.